# How to set a default value to a material ui (joy) slider on every re render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a set of sliders [image: Sliders that I will use to adjust value]

These are made using material UI (JOY). Now, my target is to set a default value for those sliders on every re-render.

[image: Dropdown containing information for slider values]

The dropdown here contains some unique IDs, which will fetch information from the database upon selection. The response will contain the default values for the sliders that I showed above.

Now, the values of each slider are stored in different usestate hooks. However I am unable to set a default value to these sliders even though I am setting the defaultValue prop to the slider component.

I have also checked, the values are getting stored in my usestate hooks, but somehow the  values are not getting passed in the sliders. What should I do?